# How to find objects in the global environment that match a pattern of two underscores in the object name

Tags: r, regex

I have several objects in my global environment. I want to create a list of some of the objects in my environment. The objects that I want specifically have the two underscores in their names and p with a number at the end of it. For instance, this is an example of the names I have; "mom_big_p1", "mom_big_p2", "mom_big_p3", "mom_small_p1", "mom_small_p2", "mom_small_p3" and so on. There are other objects that have two underscores in their name like "mom_big_rank" but the only ones that have "name_size_p$" are the ones that I want.

When I try:

```r
mom_size <- setNames(lapply(ls(pattern=".\\_p"), function(x) get(x)), ls(pattern=".\\_p"))
```

I get all of the objects I want but I also get objects that have only one underscore and a p after the underscore. Is there a way to match a pattern of two underscores with a string in between them?

Comment: Some `"^[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]*[[:digit:]]+$"` should do the job. Or, `"^[[:alnum:]]+_[[:alnum:]]+_p[[:digit:]]+$"` if the part before the last number is fixed.

Comment: if `pat` is the pattern then use `mget(ls(pattern = pat), envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sample environment:

```r
vec <- c("mom_big_p1", "mom_big_p2", "mom_big_p3", "mom_small_p1", "mom_small_p2", "mom_small_p3", "mom_big_rank")
sapply(vec, assign, 1, env=environment())

ls()
# [1] "mom_big_p1"   "mom_big_p2"   "mom_big_p3"   "mom_big_rank" "mom_small_p1" "mom_small_p2"
# [7] "mom_small_p3" "vec"
```

List objects that match your pattern:

```r
ls(pattern = "_.+_p\\d+$")
# [1] "mom_big_p1"   "mom_big_p2"   "mom_big_p3"   "mom_small_p1" "mom_small_p2" "mom_small_p3"
```

If you need something before the first underscore, try a pattern of `".+_.+_p\\d+$"`.